# I couldn't find the bug in android java

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use the SimpleCursorAdapter with a listView but ı couldn't manage it. ı'm tired of looking the bug that ı can't find. thanks for your helps.

Here is the java code.

```
public class ButceGetirenListView extends ListActivity {

    ListView listLiewGetiren;
    TextView textButceGetirList1;
    TextView textButceGetirList2;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.butcegetir);

        listLiewGetiren=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        String[] from=new String[25];
        from[0]="asa";
        from[1]="deneme";

        int[] to={R.id.textButceGetirList1,R.id.textButceGetirList2};

        adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.butcegetirlist, null, from, to, 0);
        listLiewGetiren.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.butcegiris_xml, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.birinciSayfa:
             Intent intent = new Intent(ButceGetirenListView.this, Butcegiris.class);
            startActivity(intent);          return true;

        case R.id.ikinciSayfa:

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(ButceGetirenListView.this, Butcehesapla.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

and here is the error log;

```
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.deitel.btc/com.deitel.btc.ButceGetirenListView}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:245)
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:201)
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at com.deitel.btc.ButceGetirenListView.onCreate(ButceGetirenListView.java:31)
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-03 20:48:10.922: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  ... 11 more
```

and butcegetir xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:text="@string/titleButceGetir"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dp" >

    </TextView>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dp" > 
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and butcegetirlist xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textButceGetirList1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/stringButceGetirList1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textButceGetirList2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/stringButceGetirList2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at your LogCat exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

You're currently creating your own `list` ID (by using `@+id`) instead of using Android's (under `@android:id`).

In your XML, change `android:id="@+id/list"` to:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Then, in your Java file, change `findViewById(R.id.list)` to:

```
findViewById(android.R.id.list)
```

Comment: Why does he need the Android id?

Comment: @meh Because that's how it works. A `ListActivity` will look for an object with ID `android.R.id.list`. Making his own ID means it will not be found by the Android OS, hence the crash.

Comment: Oh it is a list activity, haven't noticed that.
He should just use a normal activity instead, well that is how i'd do it.